# What is the significance of the type property in a JavaScript script tag?

Tags: javascript, types, tags

In JavaScript, both `<script src="some-javascript-file.js"></script>` and `<script src="some-javacript-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` work in my web pages. This applies to both external JavaScript code and scripts defined within html. I am aware of the `text` and `application` issues. What then is the significance of the `type` property itself in the JavaScript `<script>` tag if things work when omitted?

Comment: Refer here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of HTML 5, the `type` attribute is optional.

If it is omitted, the browser defaults to JavaScript..

For inline scripts, if you aren't putting JavaScript in the script element, then you need to specify the type to stop it being treated as JavaScript.

For linked scripts, if you aren't linking to a JavaScript script, then you need to specify the type to stop the browser making an HTTP request for it, seeing the content-type isn't JS, and then throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

For browser compatibility reasons.

The `type` attribute replaced the `language` attribute back in the days of JavaScript 1+ and you could previously specified `VBScript` for the scripting language of choice but very rarely do you ever see that today.

The `type` attribute itself is *optional*, it was used to indicate the ***content type*** also called **MIME** type. The `text/javascript` value is the default if you omit the type attribute in your script tag.